# Better way to call a generic function in the derive class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

I wonder is there a way to setup my `Base` class so that I won't need to override the derive class when calling `Activate()`. It is calling the same function with the generic type of the derive class.

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract void Activate();
}

public class A : Base
{
    public override void Activate()
    {
        Foo<A>();
    }
}

public class B : Base
{
    public override void Activate()
    {
        Foo<B>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create an intermediate generic base class for classes `A` and `B`:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract void Activate();
}

public abstract class Base<T> : Base
    where T : Base
{
    public override void Activate()
    {
        Foo<T>();
    }
}

public class A : Base<A>
{
}

public class B : Base<B>
{
}
```